# How to send Mobile Application Link For iOS and Android In SMS API from PHP?

Tags: php, android, ios, sms

I have query about SMS API. I am aware about the  SMS Gateway Integration Using SMS API

But my question is how to redirect the user to the respective marketplaces (Google Play and iOS app store) from the link sent via SMS gateway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found some solution for redirecting users to there respective marketplaces.

**Solution 1**

Use third party tools which give you a single link to send via SMS and when user click on that link they will redirect to there market places.

below are some link which help you to get that Single link for your Mobile Application.

- [One Link](http://onelink.to/)
- [Branch Metrics](https://branch.io/)
- many more

**Solution 2**

Make a web page where you have to check user's device and Conditions to redirect user to there application store. Send Web Page Link in SMS.

Hope this will help Some one.